# Как правильно сделать мультиязычный sitemap.xml?

Tags: seo, sitemap, мультиязычность

Подскажите пожалуйста как корректно прописать мультиязычный sitemap.xml

**Есть два условных сайта**

- site.ru - для России
- site.by - для Белоруссии

**Вот условная структура сайтов ( одинаковая )**

- site.ru
- site.ru/contacts
- site.ru/vacancies

- site.by
- site.by/contacts
- site.by/vacancies

Прочитав [оф.справку от Гугла](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?hl=ru) - ответа я не нашел.
Однако нашел ссылку в той же справки на [генератор sitemap](https://www.aleydasolis.com/english/international-seo-tools/hreflang-tags-generator/)

Посмотрите пожалуйста что получилось и верно ли это?
Не является ли структура избыточной для поисковой системы?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>https://site.ru</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/vacancies" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/vacancies" />
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://site.by</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/vacancies" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/vacancies" />
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://site.ru/contacts</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/vacancies" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/vacancies" />
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://site.by/contacts</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/vacancies" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/vacancies" />
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://site.ru/vacancies</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/vacancies" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/vacancies" />
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://site.by/vacancies</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/contacts" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-ru" href="https://site.ru/vacancies" />
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-by" href="https://site.by/vacancies" />
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, в вашем случае было бы правильнее сделать отдельные файлы `sitemap` для `site.ru` и `site.by`, поскольку фактически для поисковой системы это не версии сайта на разных языках, а два сайта на разных доменах.

Тот файл, который вы привели в качестве примера, больше бы подошел для структуры URL `site.com/ru/` и `site.com/by/` (с соответствующими корректировками URL).